Connecting via VS Code remote explorer to Windows machine
I tried connecting to a Windows 11 machine (from a Linux Laptop) to develop code on the Windows machine (I know, i know... wrong direction, it is how it is, cant force the Lab to change OS on their main Lab PC). The code needs to run on the Windows Host as Measurement devices are connected to it in the Lab.
OpenSSH is installed on the Windows Host and I think it is working as I can connect via normal ssh username@hostname from the terminal of my Linux Laptop.
When using the VS Code extentsion Remote Explorer to connect to the Windows machine using the same command ssh username@hostname and password i get the following error in the console of VS Code:
[18:53:31.953] > no sshd parent proc
> PS C:\Users\username> 
18:53:31.954] stderr> #< CLIXML
[18:53:31.954] stderr> <Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04"><S S="Error">gcim : Access denied _x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">At line:52 char:6_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">+ $y_=(gcim win32_process | ? processid -eq $x_).parentprocessid_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (root\cimv2:win32_process:String) [Get-CimInstance], CimException_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041003,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error"> _x000D__x000A_</S></Objs>

I'm not sure what the issue could be since the normal ssh connection via terminal works fine. Anybody knows this issue or could point me in the right direction?
I tried to add my ssh key to the authorized_keys file on the windows host but that did not lead to any changes. I still need to type in the password on both the VS Code extension and the terminal, which I find odd since I would expect it to use the key.

I tried now from a Windows machine and go a similar error:
 gcim : Access denied
 + $y_=(gcim win32_process | ? processid -eq $x_).parentprocessi    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (root\cimv2:win32_process:String
> g) [Get-CimInstance], CimException

Additionally I tried to connect from my Linux client to my own Windows host and was able to connect the VS Code remote explorer. This leads me to the conclusion that something with the Permissions of the Lab PC is different and I would need to adjust those, but I dont know which permissions would lead to the error above?

check this page and do all the steps, I think you did not do some of them and you dont have permission.(from this part: In VS Code, select Remote-SSH: Connect to Host... from the Command Palette (F1, Ctrl+Shift+P) and use the same user@hostname as in step 1...). https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh
I hope it get fix.

I think i have done all the steps
I tried it now from a windows client and got the following result:
[20:05:17.031] > gcim : Access denied 
> At line:4 char:6
> + $y_=(gcim win32_process | ? processid -eq $x_).parentprocessid
> +      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (root\cimv2:win32_process:String
> g) [Get-CimInstance], CimException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041003,Microsoft.Management.Infrastruc
> cture.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand

I think it is a problem on the windows host with permissions?
